# moment.js doesn't parse time from timestamp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I'm trying to parse a timestamp with moment.js from a json data set. When I use `moment.format('MMMM Do YYYY, H:mm:ss')`, the output is i.e. `May 25th 2361, 0:00:00` for `12351223423`. It's the same for all tested timestamps. Why doesn't it show the exact time/how to fix this?

My Angular controller:

```
$scope.timeFormat = function(timestamp) {
    var dt = moment.unix(timestamp);

    if(++recheckDate % 25 == 0)
    {
        // these vars are predefined
        today = moment().startOf('day');
        yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days');
    }

    if(dt.startOf('day').isSame(today))
        return dt.format('[Today], H:mm:ss');
    if(dt.startOf('day').isSame(yesterday))
        return dt.format('[Yesterday], H:mm:ss');

    return dt.format('MMMM Do YYYY, H:mm:ss');
};
```

The html code (stripped down, controller and app is working for other fields):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <span class="time">{{ timeFormat(item.time) }}</span>
</div>
```

EDIT: [Here](https://sebb767.de/ang/) is a online-demo. Error persists. Source is on [github](https://github.com/Sebb767/AnguLog).

Comment: `moment(12351223423).format('MMMM Do YYYY, H:mm:ss');` gives me `"May 23rd 1970, 17:53:43"`, and `moment.unix(12351223423).format('MMMM Do YYYY, H:mm:ss');` gives me `"May 24th 2361, 18:23:43"`. I'd assume something's wrong with the return values from the if conditions.

Comment: `moment.unix(12351223423).format('[Today], H:mm:ss');` gives `"Today, 18:23:43"` as expected. So i can't recreate your problem. Are you sure `item.time` has a timestamp value that is accurate to the second?

Comment: Jep, it should be. The actual dataset is `$scope.data = [{ line: 22, file: 'index.php', time: 13323123423 }]` with some more lines in it. All the other values are printed correctly.

Comment: Added an online example, see edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this took me longer than it should have...

`dt.startOf('day')` modifies `dt`, it doesn't clone.

> [`moment().startOf(String);`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)
>   Mutates the original moment by setting it to the start of a unit of
>   time.

So use [`clone()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/):

```
if(dt.clone().startOf('day').isSame(today))
    return dt.format('[Today], H:mm:ss');
if(dt.clone().startOf('day').isSame(yesterday))
    return dt.format('[Yesterday], H:mm:ss');
```

Or use some other method that doesn't modify the moment.

And when you run into problems like this, hardcode in all the numbers and use `console.log` everywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much! Coming from a OO background, I should've gotten this earlier too ;)